# Javascript date not properly converting to local time

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

I have a string called stringDate that is equal to 2023-01-20T04:48:42.327000 which is a string. This is in UTC time. I live in the Pacific timezone so the following code should return 2023-01-19T20:48:42.327Z but it's returning 2023-01-20T12:48:42.327Z. Why is this happening?

```
let date: any = new Date(stringDate);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

To force `new Date()` to parse a date time object as UTC you can append a zero time zone offset to it.

```
let date: any = new Date(stringDate + '+00:00');
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is most likely due to the fact that JavaScript's Date object assumes that the input string is in local time, not UTC. This means that the Date object is automatically converting the input string to the local time zone.

So using `.toISOString()` method, which will return a string in ISO format, including the UTC offset (represented by 'Z' at the end):

```js
let date: any = new Date(stringDate);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

This will correctly parse the input string as UTC time and output the expected result `2023-01-19T20:48:42.327Z`.

Comment: This code does not parse the provided stringDate as UTC.